# what is the name for the category of game that use a real time clock as the game time like die2nite.com

Tags: terminology

I was looking for more game like http://www.die2nite.com and http://mush.twinoid.com/
They use real time as the fictional time.
Player are given a number of action point they can use freely during a 24 hour cycle.

It was quite common to see these kind of games  10 years ago and would really like to explore some more. Any idea what the category is called and where could I find more game like this. Any more example of such games would be great,

Thanks

Comment: Would you include games like EVE-Online (skill progression based on real-world time progression) and Farmville (crops grow and wither based on real-world time) to that category?

Comment: Off the top of my head, non-monotonic? Be careful this does not lead you down the slippery slope of naively using the system's "wall clock" to represent time in-game, because people and the Operating System itself can change that. The OS will periodically change it according to an atomic clock over the Internet to correct for clock drift, and that can lead your game to think that time ran backwards!

Answer (score 1):

Any game that involves elements taken directly from present realty in real-time or things in that vein are often called "Alternate reality" games. Normally they involve getting game content through unorthodox channels like social network sites.

For instance, if the game is about an investigation, you might get a lead sent in facebook chat or as an annonymous email to your gmail account.

They are sometimes reffered to as "ARG" for short (Alternate Reality Game) and the common denominator is that they "bleed" in to the real world in some way.

Comment: thanks for this interesting category but I am not looking for game too much linked to reality, just the one that use real time like the example I provided where player have a pool of action to do in this 24 hour

Comment: I don't think that is a genre, it's a game mechanic, it is often used to encourage the user to make IAP (in app purchases) to get more action points so it's possible you are looking for freemium or free-2-play mechanics to get profit.